# Communities Lightning Container Failed To Load

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, customer-community, lightning-container

I have searched for a long time, in many places, to try and figure out why my custom VueJS app would not load in a lightning container for our customer community. Finally, after reviewing [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/10/introducing-new-content-security-policy-options-for-lightning-communities.html), I could see the issue with my lightning container:

```html
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:container 
        aura:id="notificationsAppContainer" 
        src="{!$Resource.BP_vue2_notifications + '/index.html?userId=ZCHRISTM'}" 
    ></lightning:container>
</aura:component>
```

According to the linked documentation:

> In order to expose your packaged components to relaxed CSP communities, we’ve added a new Aura Interface: lightningcommunity:allowInRelaxedCSP

> This must be present on every Lightning component that you want to make available in Relaxed CSP communities.

By adding **lightningcommunity:allowInRelaxedCSP** to the component interface, the lightning container successfully displayed in our community. Here is what the updated component looks like:

```html
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightningcommunity:allowInRelaxedCSP" access="global">
    <lightning:container 
        aura:id="notificationsAppContainer" 
        src="{!$Resource.BP_vue2_notifications + '/index.html?userId=ZCHRISTM'}" 
    ></lightning:container>
</aura:component>
```

What is the support plan for this? I am worried that support for lightning containers could shift in the near future, resulting in this app no longer rendering.